# Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I have installed `jupyter` but want to uninstall it. It however is not possible:

```
$ pip freeze | grep jupyter

$ pip3 freeze | grep jupyter
jupyter-client==5.1.0
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.3.0

$ pip3 uninstall jupyter 
Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed

$ which jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

What can I do to remove this jupyter?

**EDIT**
After: `sudo pip3 uninstall jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyter-core` I have uninstalled this 3 packages however still remaining are (2xTab):

```
$ jupyter-
jupyter-bundlerextension  jupyter-nbconvert         jupyter-nbextension       jupyter-notebook          jupyter-qtconsole         jupyter-serverextension   jupyter-trust
```

And pip says they are not there:

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep jupyter
$ pip freeze | grep jupyter
```

and when trying to remove any of them I got same eg:

```
sudo -H pip uninstall jupyter-notebook
Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter-notebook, not installed
```

So how to remove completelly those packages too?

Comment: Try `pip3 uninstall jupyter-client jupyter-console jupyter-core`

Comment: There's no one package installed called just "jupyter". As your grep shows you need to uninstall `jupyter-core`.

Comment: @jdoe It removed only 3 packages but didn't remove all of the Jupyter related packages that still are not visible to `pip`. I have put new ones in edit please see. How to remove those too?

Comment: @Iguananaut You are right but still there are some packages jupyter related and can't remove them. Can you please see my edit of the original post.

Answer (score 4):

in case you were trying to uninstall jupyter because jupyter throwing below error while running jupyter notebook
`zsh: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory`,

u can fix that without uninstalling jupyter using below command

> Python3  : pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
>
> Python2 : pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter

reference : https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/issues/127

Above steps worked for me in Mac

Answer (score 1):

The scripts you mention are provided by the pip package named `notebook`, which can be installed as part of the jupyter metapackage, but can also be installed standalone. Try

```
sudo -H pip uninstall notebook
```