# Cant remove jupyter related packages

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I have the following packages to remove (2xTab):

```
$ jupyter-
jupyter-bundlerextension  jupyter-nbconvert         jupyter-nbextension       jupyter-notebook          jupyter-qtconsole         jupyter-serverextension   jupyter-trust
```

And pip says they are not there:

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep jupyter
$ pip freeze | grep jupyter
```

and when trying to remove any of them I got same eg:

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall jupyter-notebook
Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter-notebook, not installed
```

but eg.:

```
$ which jupyter-notebook 
/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

So how to remove those packages ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001138/cannot-uninstall-requirement-jupyter-not-installed)

Answer (score 1):

run following command

```
pip3 show jupyter
```

It will give some output like

```
Name: jupyter
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.
Home-page: http://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: ipykernel, ipywidgets, qtconsole, jupyter-console, notebook, nbconvert
```

now copy on clipboard the value of Require in output, which are the packages required for jupyter

then run the following command

```
sudo pip3 uninstall -y jupyter [paste the copied content ]
```

which would be equivalent to

```
sudo pip3 uninstall -y jupyter ipykernel ipywidgets qtconsole jupyter-console notebook nbconvert
```

make sure you remove comma between package names after pasting the content

Comment: `pip3 show jupyter` show no output. I have already removed packages `jupyter-client==5.1.0
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.3.0`

Answer (score 1):

The 'packages' which you say you have to remove are in fact scripts, most (all?) of which are provided by the pip package named `notebook`. Commonly, the `notebook` package gets installed as a dependency of the metapackage named `jupyter` (as suggested in another answer), but it can also be installed without it. I would suggest you try (following `sudo` etc you listed already)

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall notebook
```