# Jupityr notebook kernel error - FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

i recently ran into some problems with some of the libraries on Anaconda so i reinstalled Anaconda and when i started it up again, The Jupityr Notebook kernel error spots this text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1543, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 148, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Steven\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I get this error when i start up and open a file. It refuses to run the code, just sitting there kinda dead. The kernel error appears in nearly all of the files opened with the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Solved this my self, appears that for some reason the kernel did not install properly. Fixed with: python -m ipykernel install --user

Answer (score 5):

The solution below worked for me. You can either run this code in command prompt in your virtual environment OR in the Anaconda prompt.

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

For detailed explanation and instructions have a look [here.](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3)

Answer (score 3):

- Open  Anaconda Prompt
- Activate your env
- type: **python -m ipykernel install    --user**
- Start your jupyter notebook

Answer (score 2):

This solution may be helpful for Windows users.

1. `pip uninstall jupyter`
2. Go to `~\AppData\Roaming` (AppData is a hidden file) and delete the folder named `jupyter` and `python`(if there exists.)
3. Delete `~\.jupyter`, `~\.ipython`.
4. pip install jupyter

I was using Jupiter without anaconda and this perfectly fixed the issue. Not sure if this works for Jupiter with anaconda.

I used this trick it worked for me, I also use Jupiter without Anaconda.

Comment: i wasted days and days in order to solve this and this solution works for me..
I will try with Anaconda as well and let you know..

Comment: What will the user lose when deleting those directories? What data is stored in them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this quick fix solved my problem

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

Reference: [Cannot uninstall requirement jupyter, not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001138/cannot-uninstall-requirement-jupyter-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same thing, but the answer was surprisingly simple for me:
I used VSCode to execute some of the code generating graphs, and the graphs came out too big in Jupyter Notebook, although I specified figsize (16,9).

Re-ran these in jupyter notebook, and it went just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was python -m ipykernel install --user --name (insert your env name her) . I can now open Jupyter notebook in my virtual environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).